# Errors in my springs MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have written a simple web app in springs but I am facing an error in running the project.The error I am facing is

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/view/UserDetails.jsp at line 22

19: <c:out value="${chat.username}:"/>
20: <c:out value="${chat.message}"/>
21: </c:forEach>
22: <form:input path="message"/>
23: <input type="submit" value="Send" />
24: </form:form>
25: <br>
```

and

```
   org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'message' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'message' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

My POJO class is

```
package com.beingjavaguys.domain;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Generated;
@Entity
@Table(name="messages")
public class Chat {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name="message")
    private String message;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }


}
```

and my `Dispatcher servlet` is

```
    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.beingjavaguys.domain.User</value>
                <value>com.beingjavaguys.domain.Chat</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>



    <bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

My JSP page is**Now I have edited the page**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Group chat | User Details</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div style="color: teal;font-size: 30px">Group Chat</div>
<br><br>
<c:url var="userRegistration" value="saveChat.html"/>
<form:form id="chatMessages" modelAttribute="chat" method="post" action="${userRegistration}">
<c:forEach items="${chat}" var="chat">
<c:out value="${chat.username}:"/>
<c:out value="${chat.message}"/>
</c:forEach>
<form:input path="message"/>
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form:form>
<br>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

My Controller is

```
@RequestMapping("/saveChat")
    public ModelAndView saveChat(@ModelAttribute("chat") Chat chat,BindingResult result){
        userService.addChat(chat);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/userList");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/userList")
    public ModelAndView getUserList() {
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("chat", userService.getChat());
        return new ModelAndView("UserDetails", model);

    }
```

I am unable to grasp the problem here(**Edited the error**).

Comment: Please add the JSP page trying to access `Chat.message`. It looks as if you are expecting an object of type `Chat`, but it is actually an `ArrayList` (which doesn't have a `getMessage(String)` method).

Comment: Hi I did the changes but stuck with different error.

Comment: model.put("chat", userService.getChat()); seems to adding ArrayList Object , and you are trying to get it as Chat Object

Comment: You are using the same var name <c:forEach items="${chat}" var="chat">. Use different names for different vars, names are for free.

Comment: The error is on the line <form:input path="message"> but I dont know how and why?

Answer (score 1):

In your JSP webpage you're trying to get `message` property of an object of class ArayList instead of `Chat`.

Maybe you should try to change modelAttribute name to avoid the name `chat` used by your list:

```
<form:form id="chatMessages" modelAttribute="chatModel" method="post" action="${userRegistration}">
<c:forEach items="${chat}" var="user">
<c:out value="${user.username}:"/>
<c:out value="${user.message}"/>
</c:forEach>
<form:input path="message"/>
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form:form>
```

and change it also in:

```
public ModelAndView saveChat(@ModelAttribute("chatModel") Chat chatModel,BindingResult result){
        userService.addChat(chatModel);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/userList");
    }
```

Comment: I did the changes but still I am geting the error and I have edited my question again.

Comment: you are using the same var name here <c:forEach items="${chat}" var="chat">, that's why you have an error.